# How can I set right KeyboardListener into my TextField in javafx Application?

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, textfield, keyevent, invocationtargetexception

I decided to create application for me. I wanted to set keyboard listener in my text field. There are 5 windows in my simple application and in the everyone has handler. All handlers different. But I can't make even one of them. it throw to me "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"...Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException and here reference to the my sentence where i set listener for my text field. I know if i create object i will never get those exceptions. I had tried it BUT the keyboard listener had't worked. HELP me please, I don't know what i need to do!

Below, is shown class, which implements EventHandler

```
package sample.Storage;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.bidimap.DualHashBidiMap;
import sample.Controllers.ControllerStudies;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class StorageElementary implements Storage, EventHandler<KeyEvent> {
    private static DualHashBidiMap<String,String> storage = new DualHashBidiMap<>();
    private static ControllerStudies controllerStudies = new ControllerStudies();

    private List<String> shuffleStorage(){
        List<String> resList = new ArrayList<>(100);
        resList.addAll(storage.keySet());
        Collections.shuffle(resList);
        return resList;
    }



    public void startWork(){
        List<String> keysList = shuffleStorage();

        for (String key: keysList) {
            controllerStudies.getTxtFieldDisabled().setText(key);        //set value, which you need translete
            controlTrue(key);                                       //implement control every character and whole word
            controllerStudies.getTxtFieldDisabled().clear();
            controllerStudies.getTxtFieldForWritten().clear();
        }

    }

    private void controlTrue(String key){
        String value = storage.get(key);        //it's need to get
        //.....
    }

    // just sout for check
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getCode().toString());
    }




    static {
        //here new words put into the storage
        storage.put("говорить", "speak");
        storage.put("рассказывать", "tell");
    }


}
```

Controller with a button :

```
package sample.Controllers;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import sample.Storage.StorageElementary;
import sample.UtilClasses.Helper;

public class ControllerMain {

    private static ControllerStudies controllerStudies = new ControllerStudies();

@FXML
    private Button btnElem;
@FXML
    void elemOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Helper.closePreviewAndShowNextWindow(btnElem,"windowStudies.fxml");
        StorageElementary storageElementary = new StorageElementary();
        controllerStudies.getTxtFieldForWritten().setOnKeyPressed(storageElementary);   //mistake in this string!
        storageElementary.startWork();

    }
```

Below, is shown controller, which has 2 text fields

```
package sample.Controllers;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class ControllerStudies {

    @FXML
    private TextField txtFieldDisabled;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtFieldForWritten;


    public TextField getTxtFieldDisabled() {
        return txtFieldDisabled;
    }


    public TextField getTxtFieldForWritten() {
        return txtFieldForWritten;
    }

}
```

Maybe somebody wants to see Helper's class. I stay it here.

```
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Helper {

    public static void open(String text){
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Helper.class.getResource("/sample/fxmlFiles/"+ text));
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Parent root = loader.getRoot();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.showAndWait();
    }

    public static void closePreviewAndShowNextWindow(Node elem, String text){
        //btnElem.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        if (elem != null) {
            Stage stage = (Stage) elem.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
            open(text);
        }
    }


    // if I want to testing my application
    public static void toConsole(String text){
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S. I already have made some app with javafx. But I don't remebmer what I have created object for TextField or Label. They have worked without it("new TextField()" or "new Label()").

Comment: [mcve] please .. your's is missing the fxml and the application class, also I doubt that it is minimal :)

Comment: I doubt that the controller instances you initialize the `controllerStudies` fields with ever come into touch with `FXMLLoader`; Without that the `@FXML` annotated fields are never written to...

Comment: Maybe I need to do something in my FXML file? I don't know, for the first time it:(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KeyListener JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163189/keylistener-javafx)

Comment: Yes, this post had answered my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had realized. I read other questions and with them help i fixed my app. At first i tried to work with FXMLLoader, but it didn't help. After I saw this questions and its [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163189/keylistener-javafx/23164250).
I had added "keyOnPressed" tag and its handler in the controller.